Why is my T-Mobile 5G keep switching from 5G to 5G UC?
I have a Samsung device. My service, which is T-Mobile, keeps switching between 5G UC and regular 5G.
Any information on this would be muchly appreciated

From what I read UC means Ultra Capacity 5G using different frequencies called mmWave. Therefore my guess is that your phone is switching between different antennas one regular 5G and the other capable of using the new frequencies thus showing 5G UC.
